# Ejecutar función Javascript después de dirigir a una página

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Tengo una función donde recojo dos valores para después pasarlos por parámetro a sus respectivas funciones. Estos dos valores los tengo en dos `input` en una página `HTML` llamada `deportes.html`
El caso es que necesito que al hacer click sobre la tabla que contiene estos `input`, redirija a la pagina llamada `partido.html` y una vez cargada esta página hay un nodo `<div id="cancha">` y dentro de este debe aparecer el tipo de cancha según el deporte seleccionado cuyo valor recojo en uno de los `input`. Lo que yo hago es ejecutar la función que añade la cancha después de redirigir la página, pero claro, esto no funciona puesto que después de redirigir el código se sigue ejecutando. Lo hago de esta manera

```
$('#partidoEncontrado').on('click','.tabla-st',function(){
    var idPartido = ($(this).find('input[name="idEvento"]').val());
    var deporteSel = ($(this).find('input[name="deporte"]').val());
    location.href='partido.html';
    tipoCancha(deporteSel);
    posicionesJugadores(idPartido);
})

function tipoCancha(deporteSel){
    switch(deporteSel){
        case 'futbolSala':
            $('#cancha').css('background-image','url("/images/cancha-fs.jpg")');
            break;
    }
}
```

No sé de que forma puedo hacerlo para que se ejecute la función `tipoCancha(deporteSel)` cuando la página `partido.html`haya sido cargada.
Gracias de antemano

Comment: Error, el código no se sigue ejecutando una vez redirigido al usuario, al contrario, cesa la ejecución del código en el momento que alcanza la redirección y aquello que estuviese después de la redirección no será ejecutado. Una forma de solucionar esto es enviar datos por GET a tu otra pagina y comprobar cada vez que se entre a tu otra pagina (se le redirija a esta) si existen los datos y si los datos son validos para ejecutar tu funcion.

Comment: De acuerdo, gracias por la aclaración. Pensaba que una característica de Javascript era que el código se seguía ejecutando, por eso a mí la función se me ejecutaba correctamente pero una vez dirigía a la otra página esa función no funcionaba puesto que ya se había ejecutado mientras se cargaba esta página. Saludos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Al redirigir, envía los parámetros necesarios:

```
$('#partidoEncontrado').on('click','.tabla-st',function(){
    var idPartido = ($(this).find('input[name="idEvento"]').val());
    var deporteSel = ($(this).find('input[name="deporte"]').val());
    location.href=`partido.html?cancha=${deporteSel}&partido=${idPartido}`;
});
```

Al cargar la página, busca los parámetros

```
// Se ejecuta cuando la página ya se cargó
$(function() {
    // Crear un objeto URL con la ubicación de la página
    let url = new URL(window.location.href);
    // Busca si existe el parámetro
    let cancha = url.searchParams.get('cancha');
    if(cancha) {
        // Si se encontró, entonces ejecuta la función
        tipoCancha(cancha);
    }
});

function tipoCancha(deporteSel){
    switch(deporteSel){
        case 'futbolSala':
            $('#cancha').css('background-image','url("/images/cancha-fs.jpg")');
            break;
    }
}
```